# "New connection" on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, connection, lan, homegroup

I have Windows 7 installed in my laptop. When I pluged eithernet to my router at home, Windows name the adapter as "Local Area Connection", when I connect my laptop at office, it name the adapter as "Local Area Connection 2". I have similar network devices and configurations at home and office.

I noticed that when Windows consider it connected to a new network, it does 2 things.

1. Change the name of the network adapter to "Local Area Connection 2" (and next time "Local Area Connection 3", etc).
2. It prompt a dialog to let me choose the network location ("Home", "Work" and "Public").

What is a "new connection" considered by Windows. Maybe ip address or DHCP settings?

Comment: Do you happen to use a docking station at work? That could have its own NIC built in.

Comment: @TheUser1024 Nah. I plug eithernet wire to the same adapter in my laptop.

Comment: The adapter should not go away when you unplug the cable; is it a USB ethernet adapter? Do you plug it into a different USB socket?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler It not gone way, Windows change the name of the adapter when it consider I connected to a new network.

Comment: @Hongbo Do you have some network management software installed that came with the laptop, maybe? Something from HP or Acer or NetGear or whoever?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Nope, clean install without any 3rd party software but drivers.

Comment: The network profile will most likely change when moving to a different network but the adapter name shouldn't change. I've never seen the behavior you're describing.